# Illustrator not respecting clipPath

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, svg

For the following [svg](https://svgshare.com/i/4w2.svg)

On inkscape it is correctly rendered as

[image: ink]

On illustrator it is rendered as

[image: ill]

Why is illustrator not applying the clip path property when importing the svg image in?

```
<clipPath id="SvgjsClipPath1009"><polygon id="SvgjsPolygon1008" points="124,58 220,24 352,24 462,67 565,222 485,272 450,273 456,628 131,625 133,267 101,267 19,218 111,68"></polygon></clipPath>
```

Comment: Because it has an incomplete svg importer. SVG is complex and there a number of ways to structure the file in waays illustrator does not  undertand them. But then even inkscape does not support all svg, and it was built to be a svg editor. On the otherhand illustrator reads nearly any EPS file you throw at it, bevcause that was what it was built for, inkscape ... not so much.

Comment: @joojaa That is an answer I'd upvote. Please refrain from answering questions in the comments.

Comment: @Vincent i suspect the user is asking what they can do for the situstion but do not voice it that way

Comment: @joojaa Thank you for you comments. Yes I also wanted to ask as to how to fix this problem? Sorry for not making that clear

Answer (score 2):

Because illustrator has an incomplete SVG importer. SVG is complex and there a number of ways to structure the file in ways illustrator does not understand them. But then even inkscape does not support all svg, and it was built to be a svg editor.

On the other hand illustrator reads nearly any EPS file you throw at it, because that was what it was built for, inkscape ... not so much.